# Upgrade Oracle Linux 7.8 (OL7) to Oracle Linux 8.4 (OL8) - Using leapp the target parameter is not respected

Tags: linux, upgrade

I have a test environment on Oracle Linux 7.8 virtualized locally with vSphere 6.5. Its working normally and is required to be taken to a specific version, to version 8.4; I have a backup and checkpoint, so it is feasible to test before performing the process.

> $ cat /etc/oracle-release >  Oracle Linux Server release 7.8

The locale corresponds to en_US.UTF-8, PermitRootLogin yes is set in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and yum update is applied to update all the packages to 7.9 (updating the kernel version); with the environment updated to 7.9, leapp is then executed indicating the desired version (as mentioned, 8.4).

> $ sudo leapp preupgrade --oraclelinux --target 8.4

There is an alert for remove_pam_pkcs11_module_check, which is confirmed to true for the installation to be done. Next, the upgrade is performed

> $ sudo leapp upgrade --oraclelinux --target 8.4

The process is followed, everything normal and the Operating System is updated well, the issue is that its upgraded to version 8.8 and not to the desired 8.4.

> cat /etc/oracle-release > Oracle Linux Server release 8.8

It seems to me that the syntax should only indicate the target version as I did.

Do you know where I'm going wrong? or, what is missing for it to update specifically to version 8.4? is it feasible?

Thanks.

Several tests have been performed indicating different target versions, but it always updates to the most recent one.

Comment: I got a response from the Oracle forum. So in summary.

Specifying the argument --oraclelinux is akin to --enablerepo ol8_baseos_latest --enablerepo ol8_appstream --enablerepo ol8_UEKR6 that would override the --target version refer.

In short, OL7 Leapp migration only supports migration to the current latest OL8 version (OL8.8 at this time).

I consider manually adding the desired non-latest repository to leapp-upgrade-repos-ol8.repo file, bt unfortunately this will unlikely work due to package dependency issues between latest ol8_appstream and older ol8_u[4,6]_baseos_base packages.